# Rename files using rename command in bash shell

Tags: bash, scripting, rename, file-rename

I have read other similar questions on the forum and I can't understand why the command I tried doesn't work.

I have a list of files named in the form aaaa_100_aaaa.csv, aaaa_100_aaab.csv, aaaa_100_aaac.csv and so on, and I want to replace "100" with "200".

I'm running bash in Windows PowerShell WSL. I tried with this command

```sh
 rename 's/420/410/g' *.csv
```

I found the same expression in many answers on the forum but it doesn't work. I got the error message

```
mv: target 'aaaa_100_aaaa.csv' is not a directory.
```

Comment: If you have `rename` from the `util-linux` package, the `s/find/replace/` isn't supported. Check your `rename` version with `man 1 rename`. If under `AVAILABILITY` it says it is part of the `util-linux` package -- you have your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the error message starts with `mv:`, and therefore apparently is produced by the `mv` ("move") command, I'm willing to bet that your `bash` has been configured to treat `rename` as an alternative name for `mv`.  So you aren't really running the `rename` command at all.

To check this, run `type rename`.  It will probably tell you that `rename` is an alias or a shell function, not the reference to the `/usr/bin/rename` executable that you expected.

You can get around this by using the full pathname to invoke `rename`:

```
    /usr/bin/rename 's/100/200/g' *.csv
```

or by writing a backslash in front of `rename` to tell `bash` to skip any special handling of the command name:

```
    \rename 's/100/200/g' *.csv
```

Of course if you're going to want to use the real `rename` often then remembering to do that every time will be annoying.  You could `unalias rename` but that only fixes it in the current shell.

The long-term solution is to prevent `bash` from treating `rename` as a shortcut.  To do that you'll first have to find out where the alias or function is being defined, and then remove that definition.  It's probably in your `$HOME/.bashrc` or `$HOME/.bash_profile` file.  If it's not there then something like `grep rename $HOME/.*` should find it.  If that doesn't find it then it might be in a system startup file that you can't (or don't want to) edit, and in that case you could get rid of it by adding `unalias rename` to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.